# How do Django signals work?

Tags: python, django, signals

How does Django's event routing system work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Django signals are synchronous. The handlers are executed as soon as the signal is fired, and control returns only when all appropriate handlers have finished.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) helpful.